# What am I missing in my Karma-Jasmine Unit Test case?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to fix some test cases in my code base and found this particular case which I cannot seem to figure out.

The test runs but it complains about `NullInjectorError: No provider for Function!`

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error messages.

Angular version: 11.2.10

Here's the test case (nothing out of the ordinary) - all the imports are included (but omitted here from brevity):

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BLADE_DATA, BladeComponent } from './blade.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

describe('BladeComponent', () => {
  let component: BladeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BladeComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [BladeComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, PortalModule ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BladeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Here's the component - also very basic:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-blade',
  templateUrl: './blade.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blade.component.scss'],
})
export class BladeComponent {

  public title: string;
  public parentTab: TabInfo;
  public showOpenTabIcon = true;

  constructor(public component: Type<any>) {}

  /**
   * Convenience function to set this base class data from the injected data object.
   *
   * @param data the data for this blade
   */
  protected setData(data: any): void {
    // ...
    // sets the data (i.e. this.title = data.title)
  }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Function -> Function]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Function!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'Function', 'Function' ] })
    at <Jasmine>
    at NullInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11102:1)
    at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11269:1)
    at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11269:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:25299:1)
    at Object.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:25013:1)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:3389:1)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:3501:1)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:14693:1)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.BladeComponent_Factory [as factory] (ng:///BladeComponent/ɵfac.js:4:42)
    at getNodeInjectable (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:3596:1)
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/navigation/blade/blade.component.spec.ts:26:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
```

Comment: Hey there, this error in general has to do with service injection. Are you using any service that should be passed to the test? remember that the test must be as complete as possible.

Comment: @JorgeGuerraPires the above is almost all the code there is... I only omitted the implementation of `setData` as it's very simple (setting local values to the ones passed in) - no additional services (that I can tell) - double-checking that in a second

Comment: I guess RouterTestingModule is internal for testing, what about PortalModule? maybe there is service on this module that should be mocked or similar

Comment: PortalModule is from `@angular/cdk/portal` - i.e.  `import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';` - Similar with `RouterTestingModule`

Comment: Indeed, your code seems simple. My suggestion is commenting, and see where the error starts. Thus, you know which part is causing this error

Comment: Yes, that's how I got to this point :) - I'll continue reducing the code to see if something hints at what's missing

Comment: Recently I had problems with ```@angular/cdk```, which was not importing. Is it working properly with you?

Comment: Seems to be.  It seems to work in other places but I have not confirmed it... checking

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @JorgeGuerraPires sadly, not yet

Comment: I am learning ng-mocks, they have several functions to mock. Maybe you could try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235146/discussion-between-jorge-guerra-pires-and-blurfus).